# Localization (Change culture globally)

Tags: asp.net-core, localization, razor-pages

I try to change language in asp.net core with razor pages and PageModels(without controllers), but the problem is my localization working just for Pages/Index Page. When i  try to switch language on another pages it is handled by their OnPost methods and got NullPointer.

```
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
    
        @foreach (var culture in cultureItems)
            {
    
                <form id="selectLanguage" asp-page="/" asp-route-returnUrl="@Context.Request.Path"
                                                          method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                    <input class="dropdown-item  waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="culture" value="@culture.Value" />
    
                </form>
            }

</div>
```

**My handler method:**

```
public void OnPost(string culture, string returnUrl)
    {
        Response.Cookies.Append(
                                                   CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
                                                   CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(culture)),
                                                   new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(1) }
                                               );

        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl ?? "/");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, I highly recommend we should take a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

If all that information make us kind of overwhelm,... then I think a brief would have some help.

Globalization and localization commonly aiming at serving multiple language for an app, and to accomplish that, it make use of

- A way to detect language of a request

Http communication was designed to be stateless, so, there's no built-in way to track something such as language. It has to be some kind of information that was attached to the Http Request, usually, in `Accept-Language` header. We can make use of cookie if we want it to.

- A mechanism to process that language

After we know the request language, use something to let the app know, the current culture for the whole request should be something that satisfy the language. In this case, a middleware that responsible to ensure `CurrentCulture` and `CurrentUICulture` was set as we want.

- Some Resource that the app make use to translate content

Usually, some resource file with extension `resx` are use, think of it as an dictionary, where we define `apple` in many other language that our site would support. Then mechanism would take care of the rest.

AFAIK, that's the general idea almost all frameworks follow. And how to implement it was expressed clearly on that above doc. Give it sometime, and things should be good.